# Tricky question involving binomial expansion

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

For given $m$, what is the highest power of $2$ that divides $[(\sqrt3 +1)^m]+1$? where $[x]$ denotes the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$.

I have no clue how to proceed.

Comment: Observations show that for $m=4k+2$ number  $2^{2k+3}$ divides expression $\lfloor (\sqrt{3}+1)^m \rfloor + 1$. Hence, one can expect "there is no *highest* power ...".

Comment: @Oleg567 For a fixed m.

Comment: About notations, $[x]$ usually denotes the closest integer, while $\lfloor x \rfloor $ is used for the greatest integer $\leq x$.

Comment: @Babai, for any even number $m$ that has form $m=4k+2$: 2,6,10,14,... .

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio From Wikipedia- "Carl Friedrich Gauss introduced the square bracket notation $[ x ]$ for the floor function in his third proof of quadratic reciprocity (1808).[2] This remained the standard[3] in mathematics until Kenneth E. Iverson introduced the names "floor" and "ceiling" and the corresponding notations $⌊ x ⌋$ and $⌈ x ⌉$ in his 1962 book A Programming Language. Both notations are now used in mathematics;"

Comment: @Babai: technically, we are closer to $1962$ than $1808$.

Comment: I am more close to Gauss than Kenneth :) And that's how we learn it in India!

Answer (score 2):

A collection of hints.

For any $m$ sufficiently large ($m\geq 3$), the closest integer to $(\sqrt{3}+1)^m$ is given by
$$a_m=(1+\sqrt{3})^m+(1-\sqrt{3})^m\tag{1}$$
and the sequence $\{a_m\}_{m\geq 0}$ fulfills the recurrence relation:
$$ a_{m+2} = 2a_{m+1} +2a_m \tag{2}$$
since the characteristic polynomial is $(x-1-\sqrt{3})(x-1+\sqrt{3})=x^2-2x-2$.
Due to the coefficients $2$ appearing in the RHS of $(2)$, it is not difficult to study
$$ \nu_2(a_m) = \max\left\{n\in\mathbb{N}: 2^n\mid a_m\right\}.\tag{3} $$
For sure, $(2)+\text{induction}$ imply that $\nu_2(a_m)\geq\frac{m}{2}$.

Comment: Why is the closest integer to $(\sqrt 3+1)^m $ is given by $a_m=(1+\sqrt{3})^m+(1-\sqrt{3})^m\tag{1}$?

Comment: @Jackk D'Aurizio: $(1-\sqrt 3)^m$ is negative if $n$ is odd. Whereas $[(\sqrt3 +1)^m]+1$ is always more than $(\sqrt 3+1)^m$ .

Comment: @Babai: I said *the closest integer*, that may differ from the greatest integer $\leq$.

Comment: Hence you are interested in $\nu_2(a_m)$ or in $\nu_2(a_m+1)$, according to the parity of $m$.

Comment: But since $\nu_2(a_m)$ is always rather large, $a_m+1$ is an odd integer.

Comment: $a_m$ is the closest integer to $(1+\sqrt{3})^m$ because $a_m$ is an integer and the absolute value of $(1-\sqrt{3})^m$ is less than $\frac{1}{2}$ for any $m\geq 3$.

Comment: What is the exact value of $\nu_2(m)$?

Comment: This way, one can consider $$a_{2s} = \left(4+2\sqrt{3}\right)^s + \left(4-2\sqrt{3}\right)^s$$ with recurrent relation $$
a_{2(s+2)} = 8a_{2(s+1)} - 4a_{2s}.$$

Comment: @Babai: you may compute it from $(2)$ with few extra-work.

Comment: As implementation of this answer... (see Binet's formula for Fibonacci Numbers too).
Denote $p=1+\sqrt{3}$, $q=1-\sqrt{3}$.
Then $p, q$ are solutions of equation $x^2=2x+2$.

Denote $$a_m=\lfloor p^m\rfloor+1.$$
Note that $p^m+q^m$ is integer for $m\in\mathbb{N}$ (why?).

Since $p^m,q^m$ are irrational, then (note that $-1<q<0$)
for even $m$:$$a_m=p^m+q^m;$$ for odd $m$:$$a_m=p^m+q^m+1.$$

That implies recurrent relations:$$a_{2s}=8a_{2(s-1)}-4a_{2(s-2)};$$ $$a_{2s-1}=8a_{2(s-1)-1}-4a_{2(s-2)-1}-3.$$
So, the highest power of $2$ for odd $m$ is $0$; for $m=4k-2$ and $m=4k$ is $2k+1$.